# How to find $\gcd(100! , 2^{100})$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

How can I find $\gcd(100! , 2^{100})$?
If I use this method:
$$100! = 2^x + y$$
How can I find $x$?

Comment: Well the answer is clearly a power of $2$ so...

Comment: Yea, it's 2^k, but how can I know what is that K ?

Comment: I suggest looking at [de Polignac's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)

Comment: Did you mean $2^xy$?

Comment: I got the answer,
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, applying *Legendre's formula*, and denoting $v_2(n)$ the exponent of $2$ in the prime factors decomposition of $n$:
$$v_2(100!)=\biggl\lfloor\frac{100}2\biggr\rfloor+\biggl\lfloor\frac{100}4\biggr\rfloor+\biggl\lfloor\frac{100}8\biggr\rfloor+\dotsm$$